# Java code in vscode console not running correctly when packaged as .jar

Tags: java, visual-studio-code

I am trying to write a simple code in java, that when run will launch the google website. Below is my code.

```
import java.awt.Desktop;
import java.net.URI;
class DoTheFunny{
    public static void main(String args[]) throws Exception{
        Desktop d=Desktop.getDesktop();
        d.browse(new URI("https://www.google.com"));
        }
    }
```

This code is working when run in vscode. However, when packaged as a .jar file and run, nothing happens. I have tried converting to a .exe and once again nothing happened. Also when extracting the .jar file I get the correct packaging information. I used the [JAR Builder](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=aslamanver.jar-builder) extension to package my code. Anyone have any idea what is wrong?

Comment: What happens when you run it from PowerShell/console? I suspect that an Exception is being thrown that you cannot see, or something is not set correctly in the jar which should be evident if running it from console.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1.Compile the .java file, which generates the .class file:

```
javac DoTheFunny.java
```

2.Create .jar:

```
jar cvfe DoTheFunny.jar DoTheFunny .\
```

3.Run the .jar by command or double-click it in the folder:

```
java -jar DoTheFunny.jar
```

[image]

Comment: This one ended up working! Thank you! I must have compiled it wrong.

Comment: at first, i used Jar Builder to build jar, but not work, so i chose to do it by command and i'm happy that my answer helps you:)

Answer (score 0):

Basically, I would say that it I don't think that is abnormal.

Even when I use command prompt and powershell, it does the same thing unless I

Package it using launch4j
or run it on the command line.

To run your jar file using command line, use the java -jar way, if it complains about a certain main entry missing, then I think you should remake your jar file using the cfe option.

I hope I helped.

Answer (score 0):

I think vscode is being a little forgiving, if you run your jar from the command line using: `java -jar DoTheFunny.jar` you'll likely see some type of exception error related to being unable to access a member of class...

You should declare your class as public, so that java "knows" where to find it when running it in the JVM.

After setting your class a public, export the jar using the plugin and try again, you'll probably see better results.

Let me know how that works out for you.