# Java .jar file doesn't run, but it runs in VSCode

Tags: java, swing, visual-studio-code, jar, linkageerror

I am using VSCode. When in VScode, I press F5 to run my java app, it runs successfully. The problem is when I click the export jar button, it builds the .jar file, but when I double click on the .jar file, it doesn't run. I am not using any build tools. I am also using java swing.

When I run from the console it outputs:

```
Error: LinkageError occurred while loading main class Main java.lang.UnsupportedClassVersionError: 
    Preview features are not enabled for Main (class file version 59.65535). –
```

Comment: Try launching the jar from the command line (e.g. `java -jar <jarfile>`). What output do you see?

Comment: Great advice from @Slaw. Make sure that every `catch` in the code either dumps the stack trace or otherwise logs the problem.

Comment: It outputs: Error: LinkageError occurred while loading main class Main
        java.lang.UnsupportedClassVersionError: Preview features are not enabled for Main (class file version 59.65535).

Comment: @Slaw See new comment from OP.

Comment: And if you do `java --enable-preview -jar <jarfile>` does the application run normally?

Comment: Yes it does, thank you. Do you know if there is a way to enable this by default?

Comment: I don't know a way for executable jars, unfortunately. At least not directly. You can create a script that launches your jar with the needed jvm arguments. Or you can try packaging your application with something like launch4j and specify the arguments. Since you're using Java 14+ you can also check out [jpackage](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/15/jpackage/packaging-overview.html#GUID-C1027043-587D-418D-8188-EF8F44A4C06A). Another option is to remove your use of preview features in your code and not have to worry about this.

Comment: Try to manually export the project as a jar by command. please refer to [Java code in vscode console not running correctly when packaged as .jar](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64435237/java-code-in-vscode-console-not-running-correctly-when-packaged-as-jar/64442614#64442614)